# Using visual studio code and when saving my code with Ctrl + S

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

I am initiating a react-native code on visual studio code,
since it is initialized and just printing out the default template, so it was fine,
But as soon as I enter Ctrl+S
then the codes automatically changes weirdly and then it shows error as "Error : Text strings must be rendered within a  component."

For example, the codes were initially

```
export default function App() {
    return ( 
        <View style = { styles.container }>
        <Text > Open up App.js to start working on your app! </Text>
        </View>    
        
        );
```

But if I enter Ctrl +S, then it changes weirdly as

```
export default function App() {
    return ( <
        View style = { styles.container } >
        <
        Text > Open up App.js to start working on your app! < /Text> <
        /View>    

    );
}
```

If I rearrange this and then enter Ctl+S, then it again changes the code weirdly like above so I cannot run the code...

Would anyone knows solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can only return one element in a component. If you want to return more than one component, wrap them in a  or use a fragment.

```
export default function App() {
    return (
       <> 
        <View style = { styles.container }>
        <Text > Open up App.js to start working on your app! </Text>
        </View>    
       </>
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the extensions you have installed or uninstall the app